# how to store API response in an array in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, dependency-injection

i have a service that returns an API response of type json, in this json object i have a list of number values.i can output those values on my webpage, but i would like to store the values in an array first to do some calculations on. i have tried many ways without success. please guide me

[API response screenshot in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV5k5.png)

### http call service

```
getTriggerCount():Observable<Trigger>{

  return this.http.get(this.triggersUrl).pipe(
    flatMap(count => transformAndValidate(Trigger, count)))
```

### component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-triggers',
  templateUrl: './triggers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./triggers.component.css']
})
export class TriggersComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input() trigger: Trigger;

  constructor(private triggerService: DbApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

this.getTriggerCount();

  }

  getTriggerCount(){
 this.triggerService.getTriggerCount() .subscribe(trigger => this.trigger = trigger);

  }

}
```

Trigger Class

```
import { IsNumber, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator'; 

export class Trigger { 
    @IsNotEmpty() 
    @IsNumber() 
    result: number[]; 
    constructor() { } 
}
```

Comment: hey igor, no it is not a duplicate, as the problem is not in getting the response or in asynchronous calls. i get the response right. but i want to take the response and save into an array to work on this array. i think its a problem of misconception in how i manipulate and structure the data that come from the api response

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your service, it should be like the following

```
getTriggerCount():Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(this.triggersUrl).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Using the new `HttpClient` it should like like this:

```
getTriggerCount():Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get<any>(this.triggersUrl);
}
```

To make use of this in the component. You also do not need the `@Input()` for `trigger`. Your `Trigger` class is also over complicated for what you are doing. See below

```
public trigger: any;

getTriggerCount(){
    this.triggerService.getTriggerCount()
        .subscribe(trigger => this.trigger = trigger);
  }
```

This will then have the response on the `trigger` object. If you want to make use of the object, to say, add all the numbers together, you would do the following:

```
addArray() {
    let sum = this.trigger.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0);
}
```

The `+a` and `+b` is to convert the item to a number. This won't work if the item can't convert to a number.

Comment: i have made a mistake in copying the service bit of my code i have fixed it. the problem is not with the api response, i get it, and i can display it on my webpage. what i want is to store this response in a normal numbers array so i can do some calculations on the api response before i render it on my webpage.

Comment: What does `Trigger` look like?

Comment: import { IsNumber, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class Trigger {
    @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumber()
   result: number[];

   constructor() { 
  }
}

basically i add the transform-validate func to transform the object to a class, as i thought it would be easier to deal with it as a class to get the data, but also proved to be tricky for me

Comment: Can you give an example of the json object you receive back from the API?

Comment: i have a attached a screenshot of the response in postman in a link. basically its some number plain numbers i get from my database